# Overwrite a node package in ember

Tags: node.js, ember.js

How do I overwrite a package in node within ember?  For example, a particular component is located here:

*node_modules/module/app/templates/components/module_code.hbs*

If I edit that file directly, it of course will be overwritten with an upgrade.  Can I put the same file:

*module_code.hbs*

somewhere in my Ember App structure to make adjustments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can put the same file here:

*your_ember_project/app/templates/components/module_code.hbs*

and adjust it as necessary.